# Use of methods of Parse in Cron job: Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, cron

I am trying to write a Cron Job. I have to use various methods of Parse in it. I have following code in my hand:

```
var crontab = require('node-crontab');
var jobId = crontab.scheduleJob("* * * * * *", function(){
                            console.log("Hello there! It's me again.");
                            Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
                            });
```

But, when I run

**node fileName.js**

command from Terminal, it gives me an error:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
^                                

ReferenceError: Parse is not defined
```

Additionally, if I try to install any module using

```
npm install *****
```

then, it is also not working for me.

I would like to know what is there being missed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting with npm?

Answer (score 1):

To use Parse you need to `require` the module.

```
var Parse = require('parse');
```

Comment: Thanks bolav for your time .!
But, I need to use various methods of Parse such as 'Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()', 'Parse.Object.extend()'..
If I declare 'Parse' at the top, then how can I use these methods.

Comment: Just like you say. You need to declare it to be available.

Comment: Hi bolav. Sorry, I didn't tell you that the methods that I have mentioned are in-built i.e. given by Parse. So if I manually declare Parse object, then I won't be able to call such methods.

Comment: You still have to declare the Parse object manually to be able to use the built-in Parse methods. Parse is not part of the base JavaScript library.